# PHP or PHPUnit custom function

Tags: php, phpunit

Here is my custom function in PHPUnit.

```
protected function checkIfSetGlobalTest($VARIABLE, $ASSIGNMENT) {
    global $VARIABLE;
    if(!isset($VARIABLE) == true) {
        $VARIABLE = $ASSIGNMENT;
    }
}
```

Here is when I call that function.

```
protected function setUp() {
    $this->checkIfSetGlobalTest("$URL", "http://google.com");
    $this->setBrowser("*firefox");
    $this->setBrowserUrl($URL);

}
```

I want to see if the variable is set, if not, then assign that URL to that variable. Like the code below.

```
global $URL;
if(!isset($URL) == true) {
    $URL = "http://google.com";
}
```

Comment: Obligatory 'don't use global' comment, especially seeing how you're passing `$VARIABLE` into your first function anyway.  And if you're using PHPUnit, why aren't you using one of its `assert` functions?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need [variable-variables.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

You could use this feature like this:

```
protected function checkIfSetGlobalTest($VARIABLE, $ASSIGNMENT) {
    $VARIABLE = ltrim($VARIABLE, '$');
    global $$VARIABLE;
    if(!isset($$VARIABLE) == true) {
        $$VARIABLE = $ASSIGNMENT;
    }
}
```

or just use [$GLOBALS superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php):

```
protected function checkIfSetGlobalTest($VARIABLE, $ASSIGNMENT) {
    $VARIABLE = ltrim($VARIABLE, '$');
    if(!isset($GLOBALS[$VARIABLE]) == true) {
        $GLOBALS[$VARIABLE] = $ASSIGNMENT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the first variable by reference in order to modify it within your function:

```
protected function checkIfSetGlobalTest(&$VARIABLE, $ASSIGNMENT)
```

Also, you should not pass your variable quoted when you pass it, or it will pass the value.

```
$this->checkIfSetGlobalTest($URL, "http://google.com");
```

Doing these, you will not need to use `global` in your function to check whether it is set.

Comment: I'm using global because I used $URL variable in my TestSuite.xml file. If it's not set when I'm running the test cases one by one instead of the TestSuite, I would like to assign that variable to something.

Comment: If you are passing by reference, you don't need global. The $URL variable is passed into the function as-is and you don't need to know the variable name for anything.